# how to right pad a unicode string with space and display it to a fixed length?

Tags: html

OK title can't explain it well.

I need a few lines of unicode strings, which are of the same fixed length. For example,

#1 aabb                  999

#2 とうきょう        120

#3 good morning f    60

#4 Привет                51

#5  ...

I can divide each row of the texts into 3 parts. Here the hash with a number means the rank, the string means the name, and the numbers at the end means the score. Note that the third row's name is "good morning friend" but the line is trimmed to "good morning f".

So I have problem padding the name and the score into the correct format, which aligns the row both to the left and to the right.

I am using a div to hold these texts.Currently I am using a span for each line. But I don't know how to pad the strings correctly for different kinds of characters. Anyone has a better idea?

**UPDATED**:

**I managed to do it with a `<table>` tag. It looks very nice.**

Comment: use a `<table>` with rows (`<tr>`) and columns (`<td>`) instead. this would be the best solution you can achieve!

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Can it pad strings to the right correctly? If `<span>` can do the same I am happy with that.  In fact I am doing this in the `innerHTML` attribute of the `div` so I don't want to make my code too ugly.

Comment: With a table you don't need any string padding. It will correctly align all the columns by itself. Your data is exactly what tables are for.